# i want to create json object dynamically & retrive data from json to display all ercords

Tags: html, json

I have created one registration form. For every submit,i want to store all the form data into json object.is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I cant add a comment so ill post an "answer". I believe this question is answered [Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-js-object-with-jquery)